# Calculating growth based on seasonality

Tags: excel

Who can put me on the right way with my calculations in Excel?

What I want to achieve is that when I change my growth % (Cell B2) the monthly deals of table “Year 2” (rows B14:M14) adjust accordantly based on the seasonality (rows B13:M13).
Cell N14 needs to be the SUM of cells B14:M14. Of course cell N14 is cell N8* my growth %(Cell B2).

So to recap, when I want to achieve a growth of x(Cell B2) in Year 2 based on the numbers of Year 1 (rows B10:M10), then how many deals (rowsB14:M14) do I need to do every month based on the seasonality(rows B13:M13).

[image]

Comment: Start by having your seasonality add up to 100%?

Comment: @a-burge. I've updated the table and adjusted the seasonality to 100%

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be 0%. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First, your seasonality needs to add to 0% (otherwise it suggests growth as well). I'm also assuming that you are not after compound growth.

Once that's in place try: `=$N$8*(1+$B$2)/12*(1+B7)` in `B14` and fill to the right.

Comment: what I don't get is the seasonality. How can this be 0%?

Comment: The items labelled "Seasonality" are not seasonal factors. They are factors which relate the current month's value to the preceding month. The assumption that Year 2's "seasonals" are the same as Year 1, is incompatible with an arbitrary growth level for Year 2 overall. If the same pattern of demand  (as represented by the "seasonals") is assumed for year 2 as year 1, multiply each month in year 1 by (1+growth) to get corresponding month in  year 2 and then calculate the January "seasonal"for year 2, rather than arbitrarily assuming it is zero.

Comment: Have a look at this as well @WouterS, in case you want more background: http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/205420/Time-series-forecasting-understanding-trend-and-seasonality.